# Slick.js - different delays between slides

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm using [Slick Slider](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/) to display some slides. I need to be able to have different delays between the slides.

This is what I have so far - it works for the first slide, but it gets stuck on second slide. 
The error is not so useful for me: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null" - slick.min.js:17.

The code:

```
var $slideshow = $('.slider');
var ImagePauses = [6000, 2000, 3000, 10000, 4000];

// Init
modifyDelay(0);

// Sliding settings
$slideshow.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  modifyDelay(currentSlide);
});

// Slider config
function modifyDelay(startSlide) {
  $slideshow.slick({
    initialSlide: startSlide,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: ImagePauses[startSlide],
    fade: true
  });
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vxxhnga5/2/).

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are actually creating a new SlickJS instance upon `afterChange`--that is probably not what you want. What you need is simply to update the slick options after every slide change so that the autoplay speed is changed.

SlickJS [exposes a method called `slickSetOptions`](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/#methods) that allows you to modify settings on the go.

What you can do is to discard the `modifyDelay()` function entirely. Instead, when the `afterChange` event is fired, you can use `.slick('slickSetOptions', 'autoplaySpeed', <yourSpeed>', true)` to set the new autoplay speed:

```
$slideshow.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    $slideshow.slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplaySpeed', ImagePauses[currentSlide], true);
});
```

Note that the positional arguments for `slickSetOption` are as follow:

1. **The option name** (for that, refer to available [settings/option/config of the plugin](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/#settings))
2. **The value that you want to assign**--in this case, we are simply extracting the value from your `ImagePauses` array based on index
3. **Boolean to indicate if the UI needs to be refreshed**. I don't think the UI is refreshed when you are simply adjusting the autoplay speed, so `false` will be a safe bet, but I used `true` in my example to future-proof your setup.

Here is a proof-of-concept example, I have added `console.log()` so that you know what values are set after each `afterChange` event is fired:

```js
$(function() {
  var $slideshow = $('.slider');
  var ImagePauses = [6000, 2000, 3000, 10000, 4000];

  // Init
  $slideshow.slick({
    initialSlide: 0,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: ImagePauses[0],
    dots: false,
    fade: true
  });

  // Sliding settings
  $slideshow.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    // Console log, can be removed
    console.log('Current slide: ' + currentSlide + '. Setting speed to: ' + ImagePauses[currentSlide]);

    // Update autoplay speed according to slide index
    $slideshow.slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplaySpeed', ImagePauses[currentSlide], true);
  });

});
```

```css
.panel {
  border: 10px solid #333;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="panel">1</div>
  <div class="panel">2</div>
  <div class="panel">3</div>
  <div class="panel">4</div>
  <div class="panel">5</div>
</div>
```

You can also check out your modified fiddle that now works :) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/vxxhnga5/7/

Comment: I'm impressed, man. I almost gave up on this one. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Meek Glad that I'm able to help. I do have to let you know that there is currently no implicit checks: you will probably get an error if your `ImagePauses` array length is less than the number of slides. A simple check before setting the option will work (which you might want to implement a default playback speed).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vxxhnga5/8/

I have do small change in your code

```js
var $slideshow = $('.slider');
var ImagePauses = [6000, 2000, 3000, 10000, 4000];

// Init
modifyDelay(0);

// Sliding settings
$slideshow.on('change', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  modifyDelay(currentSlide);
});

// Slider config
function modifyDelay(startSlide) {
  $slideshow.slick({
    initialSlide: startSlide,
    autoplay: true,
    fade: true
  });
}
```

```css
.panel {
  border: 10px solid #333;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="panel" >1</div>
    <div class="panel" >2</div>
    <div class="panel">3</div>
    <div class="panel">4</div>
    <div class="panel">5</div>
  </div>
```